# mysql PHP comparing values in two tables

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have two tables: "user" and "grade"

my "user" table looks like this:

```
id|username|password|email
```

my "grade" table looks like this:

```
studentid|names|exam1|exam2|...
```

I want to compare "id" column from the **user** table with "studentid" column from **grade** table. If the logged in user has an id 5 then I would need to pull out studentid 5 with "names, exam1, exam2" from the **grade table** and display it in html format. How do I do this?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `JOIN` both tables,

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    user a
        INNER JOIN grade b
            ON a.ID = b.StudentID
WHERE   a.ID = 5
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
SELECT  names, 
        exam1, 
        exam2
FROM  grade g
   INNER JOIN user u
      ON u.id = g.studentid
WHERE u.id = 5
```